# tile breaks over to second page when printing google maps

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

Printing Google Maps in Chrome/Edge both break the last row of tiles to the second page. The full tile is shown on the second page, instead of the partial area displayed on the map.

I tried doing break-after:always on the map area, and a second div after it with break-before:always. It didn't help.

Any ideas on how to prevent the last row of tiles from breaking to the second page?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that printing is not supported in Google Maps JavaScript API.

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#print

> Printing from the JavaScript API is not supported. This is because printing support is inconsistent across commonly used browsers. **We recommend using the Static Maps API** for printing purposes.

Comment: Yet hacks are still possible. Static Maps doesnt work because the tiles generated arent big enough.